# Optimising simulation parameters - is it possible to produce regression style diagnostics such as p values?

Tags: statistical-significance, simulation, optimization

Let's say I have a black box simulation of some sort.  It takes a couple of input parameters, and then outputs data.  The output can be checked for fit against real world data.

Suppose I optimize the input parameters, by brute force, gradient descent or otherwise.  The optimisation maximises model fit, measured by $r^2$ or any other suitable measure.

If this was a regression model my optimal parameters would be the $\beta$.  Is there any way I can get other parameter diagnostics from this process - equivalents to $t$ and $p$ values in regression?  The aim would be to test the significance of each input parameter.

***UPDATE*** the black box simulation is a kind of traffic simulation.  So given input of where people live, destinations, a network distance matrix between these points using a definition of distance that is also parameterized[1], and parameters to determine how far people travel, it works out where traffic will likely build up.

[1] the relationship between parameterization of distance and the distance matrix is highly nonlinear as changing definition of distance will sometimes change the set of shortest paths.  This is why I present the model as a black box.

Comment: In case you are searching for solutions, it might help to understand that $t$ and $p$ would usually be termed *statistics*, while regression *diagnostics* are tools to assess whether the model is appropriate: various residual plots and associated information such as DFFITS, DFBETAS, PRESS, etc. As far as your question goes, it's not really answerable in the absence of a probabilistic model and a definite null hypothesis, for without those the word "significance" has no well-defined meaning. This suggests you ought to amplify your post with relevant information about this "simulation."

Comment: @whuber Thank you for clarification, I need model statistics then.  For more details see my update

Comment: Thank you--that's an interesting application.  But what does "model fit" mean?  What is the model to which you are comparing the simulated results?

Comment: Measured flows of traffic

Comment: OK, but what is your null hypothesis?  You are adjusting all parameters of the simulation to match the data as closely as possible; that's fine.  But there's no testable hypothesis involved in that, nor is one even implied.

Comment: Two possible hypotheses to test.  1. If you keep aside some data and don't use it to fit the model, then the fitted model will predict the test data.  (Or 2. If we modify the network in some way, then the fitted model will predict the changes to measurable data that arise from modifying the network).  Focusing on 1 you can easily measure whether the whole model fits the test data set, but how to compute a significance value for each model parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can approximate the likelihood by how many simulations match the real data and could then try to get a handle on observed Fisher Information, alternatively you could try to get some likelihood ratio test (either is a bit tricky and your approximation to the likelihood may need some smoothing out).

If you are willing to be Bayesian, then you can consider Approximate Bayesian Calculations.

Comment: Can either of these be used to measure absolute likelihood rather than likelihood ratio?  I'm willing to consider being Bayesian, it looks like I'd need $p(D)$ to get absolute likelihood from ABC: how do I calculate that?  Can I derive it from the same multiple samplings of the model I used to get $P(D|\theta)$?  (variables defined as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_Bayesian_computation )

Comment: On the topic of your first suggestion, I haven't encountered FIsher information before, does this also require multiple samplings of the model?  as many as Bayesian techniques?